# Find the range of an irrational function

Tags: functions

Find the range of given function: $y=-\sqrt{3x^2+4x+3}$. I don't know how to find the range of an irrational function. Can someone explain to me? Also it would be awesome if there are some excersises about this topic! (You can't use calculus here)

Comment: It's well-defined in $\mathbb R$ whenever $3x^2+4x+3\geq0$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

\begin{align}
y
&=-\sqrt{3\left(x+\frac23\right)^2+\frac53}\\
&\le-\sqrt{\frac53}\\
\end{align}
So the range is $y\in\left(-\infty,-\sqrt{\frac53}\right]$.

Comment: Truly ingegnous :-)

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Is there any other way to solve this problem?

Comment: @NikaChelidze To work out the range of this function you need to know the range of the inner quadratic. This is typically done using calculus to find it's minimum but I used completing the square instead.